# Typescript interface for a nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm new to Typescript and I have to build an interface for the following props type:

```
const myProps = [
  {
    name: 'name1',
    on: true,
    children: [
      { name: 'test1', href: '#' },
      { name: 'test2', href: '#' },
      { name: 'test3', href: '#' }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'name2',
    on: false,
    children: [
      { name: 'test1', href: '#' },
      { name: 'test2', href: '#' },
      { name: 'test3', href: '#' },
      { name: 'test4', href: '#' },
      { name: 'test5', href: '#' }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'name3',
    on: false,
    children: [{ name: 'test1', href: '#' }]
  }
];
```

I want to create an interface for it to be used in a React + Typescript app.

This is the interface so far:

```
export interface IChildren {
  name: string,
  href: string
}

export interface IMyProps {
  name: string,
  on: boolean,
  children: IChildren,
}
```

It is not working, it should have some arrays I guess. Any suggestions?

Comment: Type of `children` property in `IMyProps` should be an array, either `Array<IChildren>` or `IChildren[]`

Comment: @Wazeed why don't you convert your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this,

```
 export interface CommonProps {
    name: string;
    href: string;
}

export interface MyProps {
    name: string;
    on: boolean;
    children: Array<CommonProps>;
}
```

> Also Note data interfaces should not start with naming conventions
> `"I"` Interfaces those have method declarations should have `"I"` like
> `IMethodService`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using two interfaces you can use the following two methods.

```
  export interface ChildrenProp {
        name: string,
        href: string
    }

  export interface MyProps {
        name: string;
        on: boolean;
        children: ChildrenProp[]
    }
```

or

```
    export interface MyProps {
        name: string;
        on: boolean;
        children: Array<ChildrenProp>
    }
```

If you are not using two interfaces you can use the following method

```
export interface MyProps {
    name: string;
    on: boolean;
    children: {
       name: string,
       href: string
    }[]
}
```